# Why might I not want to convert all iterables to something with a defined length (such as a list) right away?

Tags: python

I am not sure why I wouldn't always convert to a list. Why might I not want to convert all iterables to something with a defined length (such as a list) right away?

Comment: what happens when your source data is too large to fit into memory? Especially if you can handle your data atomically, there's no need to allocate all that memory (and potentially blow up your RAM)

Comment: Why *would* you want to? Often, actually most of the time, I only need to iterate over an iterable. I don't care about its length. Suppose I'm using something like a `map` object. Why needlessly waste the memory to convert it to a list?

Comment: I guess that's right. Thanks for helping.

Comment: additional thought: if your data takes a while to compute, you wouldn't want to spend all that time computing all the elements of your list, if you only ever need one at a time. You could be processing each one, while more are being computed simultaneously

Comment: What it your iterable doesn't have a size? Say you're repeatedly polling something or simply using an infinite generator (like `itertools.count`). It is not possible to make that into a list and as others said, why would you even want that as a list? Most times we just need to ***iterate*** over something. Then use an ***iterator*** instead of a list